# How to export a HTML view page as ppt using Django ,angularJS and BIRT.?

Tags: html, angularjs, django, python-2.7, birt

I have tried pptx, but my college said specific to go with BIRT.
But its a jar file and i am using Django and angularJS so not sure how to bind BIRT with Django.

Comment: [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP66Swlq_SAhURO7wKHQOKBGUQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.opentext.com%2Fintegrating-birt-with-django%2F&usg=AFQjCNGSm_Ln3j6Z_0zVj3CDiCPCrEVd2w)

Comment: [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP66Swlq_SAhURO7wKHQOKBGUQFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.actuate.com%2Fcommunity%2Fforum%2Findex.php%3F%2Ftopic%2F29179-how-would-i-integrate-birt-with-python-django%2F&usg=AFQjCNFZckjYvKQ_OPZoyZD2eu9Q99qFKw)  should these help ?